# Merging two Tables using Scaffold & Rails (Rails noob)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to coding (never taken a CS class and have a very very minimalist understanding of the MVC architecture) and working on a test project to learn it :-) I want to setup some tables tables:

Table 1:

Table_1 ID | Name | Attribute_1 | Attribute_2 | Attribute_3 | etc

```
1      | Blah | attribute 1 | attribute 2 | attribute 3 |
```

Table 2:

Table_2 ID   | Skill       |

```
 1       | nun_chucks  |
 2       |     bow     |
 3       |     arrow   |
```

Table 3:

Table_3 ID | Primary_1 ID | Primary_2 ID |

```
 1     |     1        |      1       |
 2     |     1        |      2       |
 3     |     1        |      3       |
```

And then be able to visualize the data so it reads like:

---

Name | nunchucks, bow, arrow | attribute 1 | attribute 2 | attribute 3 |

---

I have used Scaffold to create the MVC for Table 1 & 2 and have the #page for each one respectively. I am not sure how to combine them to create table 3 and then make the data show as I am asking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good reference for what you're doing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: you sir, have been very helpful. This is relevant to my interests. http://myfacewhen.com/images/244.jpg

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN is what you want which is a database operation.

Take a look in your database servers manual and read up on it.

Essentially it takes two tables, joins them by a given column (for instance, Table_2.ID and Table_3.ID) and spits out a summary of both tables joined leaving out columns that don't match across the tables.

Comment: Thanks! This helps... Also, I have never taken a CS course and know very very little about Databases. Where is a good place to read about it online?

Comment: See my answer for a reference.  Is your end goal simply to make the output in the view as you describe?  If so, I am wondering why you need table 3 because I believe you can get the output you want using embedded ruby and html and just table 1 and table 2.  Probably would want an association between table 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, 
and the following contoller in Rails 3

```
class SomeController < ActionController
   def show
       @table_1 = Table1.find(params[:id],:include => :table2)
       # Table1 and Table2 are your models
       # where table2 would be your has_many_and_belongs_to_many assoc in Table1
   end
end
```

you could write this up in show.html.erb like

```
<%= @table_1.name %>
<%= @table_1.table_2.map(&:skill) %>
<%= @table_1.attribute_1 %>    
<%= @table_1.attribute_2 %>
<%= @table_1.attribute_3 %>
```